# Monolithic (vs) Micro-services ==> Threads (vs) Process

Tags: multithreading, process, docker, microservices

I have a monolithic application with single process having 5 threads. Each thread accomplishes certain specific task. Thinking to move this application to microservices using dockers. If I look at the architecture, each worker thread would become a docker process. So, in some way Monolithic vs Microservices becomes more like Thread vs Process discussion in my case.

The original thinking of having the monolithic was to have threads for performance and share the same memory. Now with microservices arch, I am pushed to a process model that may not suit from performance point of view.

I am kind of stuck on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Processes can crash independently. That, however, has nothing to do with docker.

Comment: There is no one-answer: and any answer leading to an implementation should take a good look at the goals/scope, current architecture, and carefully weigh in the advantages/disadvantages of different distributed and/or concurrent approaches..

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how you think Docker can help you here? Is it purely a case of packaging identical processes?

Comment: What's wrong with deploying your *current* application with docker or as a microservice???  The comparison is completely wrong even though it's often repeated. In fact, it's one of the *serious* problems of the microservices narrative. Cross-thread communication is a few orders of magnitude slower than multithreading. Going to microservices adds several orders of delay due to needles networking, serialization.

Answer (score 22):

What you are missing here is that microservices is not suitable for any software system in the world! Think about the drivers for migrating your current monolithic system to microservices before doing anything. Are you seeking for high availability and scalability? Do you want to have freedom for writing each thread in different programming languages? Is your system that complicated that could not be comprehended in a monolithic style? and finally, are you ready for paying the expenses of having a microservices style?

Microservices brings in many complexities to the system and may cause performance penalties in favor of higher scalability due to chattiness of services. If performance is an important concern, the system is not that large, and your answer to most of the above questions is "NO", I strongly suggest that you do not go for microservices style. Instead, try to modularize your current code base and refactor the code for better quality and comprehensibility.

Regarding Docker, you can use it even with the monolithic style in order to remove some of the deployment barriers and inconsistency in the development and the deployment environments. If the mentioned issues around deployment do not bother you, do not go for docker either since it will be just a layer of computational overhead.

Comment: If you find this answer useful, please mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Microservice will gain your application a more power , but this depend how size your project , what is the degree of the availability do you need ,  Do you have a lot of teams , a lot of languages and extra

Microservice for some project will be over kill and this can be handled within multithreading , so you can think about your vision before to migrate to this Architecture ,